# What is the order of lookup Maven dependencies?

Tags: maven, nexus

I need to add a jar say `abc.jar` *(available in maven central repo)*. But this is compiled with Java 8. I am using java 7 so I am getting **major minor version error**.

Since project is open source and available on GitHub. I build it locally after Changing java version in maven compiler plugin in `pom.xml`. It worked for me.

Now I uploaded this jar to local Nexus repository.

What is order of lookup here. Since jar with same name is available in maven central repo. While building my project  is this jar picked from local nexus or maven central repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local cache (the `~/.m2/repository`) has the highest precedence and then it's up to the order of the repositories declared in your `pom.xml` or your `~/.m2/settings.xml`. The maven central is implicitly added as the last one (afaik).

So, if you add your local Nexus repo to that pom declaration, you should be fine.

Also you can override the central repository by your own as described [here](https://coderwall.com/p/zr6bga/stopping-maven-from-trying-to-access-its-central-repository), but I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 3):

You should not re-deploy it using the same version number.  Non-snapshot releases of artifacts in Maven should never be overridden.  Even though all you have done is change the version compiling the source, you are effectively creating a new artifact.

You do have options, though, to support what you're doing.  You could either

- Deploy using a different group and/or artifact id which is specific to your artifact.
- Deploy using the same artifact/group/version, but use a classifier (java8, as an example).  Using a classifier allows additional artifacts to be deployed at the same namespace.

Either of these options prevent you from having to worry about lookup order, which is not something you have full control over.